# Spring Boot testing with Junit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

Using Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

The goal of the test is have a service call a controller in the same app.

Here is the simplified setup I am trying

The app class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The controller class

```
@RestController
public class EmpCtrl {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmpCtrl.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmpDao empDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/emp01", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Emp> findAllEmp01() {
        logger.trace("running my.demo.controller.findAllEmp01");
        List<Emp> emps = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<Emp> results = this.empDao.findAll();
        results.forEach(emp -> {emps.add(emp);});
        return emps;
    }
}
```

The service class

```
@Service
public class GetEmpSrv {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetEmpSrv.class);

    public void getEmps01(){
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/emp01";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        logger.debug(result);
    }
}
```

and the Junit class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StartApp.class)
public class GetEmpSrvTest01 {

    @Test
    public void doCall() {
        GetEmpSrv getEmpSrv = new GetEmpSrv();
        getEmpSrv.getEmps01();
    }
}
```

This is being run inside Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)

in the console it appears Spring Boot is running .. ic the load of h2 db and /emp01 is being mapped however in the Failure Trace of Junit ic

```
I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/emp01": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This makes me think the embedded Tomcat is not running. When I start Spring normally /emp01 returns a JSON as expected.

My question is: Is this type of testing possible with Junit? If so what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, please autowire TestRestTemplate. The reason is that your spring test will run on another port and the call to http://localhost:8080 will fail.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StartApp.class)
public class GetEmpSrvTest01 {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void doCall() {
        // without http://localhost:8080, testRestTemplate it will handle it for you
        testRestTemplate.getForObject("/emp01", String.class);
    }
}
```

Also you can expect a list of objects in your test:

```
List<Emp> emps = testRestTemplate.getForObject("/emp01", List.class);
```

Comment: worked for a good amount of the question, mainly did not see how to test the http call in the service which is mainly what I wanted to do.